# How to replace exec () through system command in php?

Tags: php

My Coding is so far:

How  to replace  `exec()`  through system command in php?

```
if($str!="success")
{
    $cmd = "rm -rf /portal/data/config/certificate/tmp/";
    $error_text="Command : ".$cmd;
    AddLog("sslconfig.php",$error_text,ERR_DEBUG_HIGH);
    $output = exec($cmd,$array1,$error_code);
    $error_text="Error code : ".$error_code;
    AddLog("sslconfig.php",$error_text,ERR_DEBUG_HIGH);
    seterror('0:|:  :|: Could not apply certificate.');
    $error_text="Could not apply certificate";
    AddLog("sslconfig.php",$error_text,ERR_INFO);
    header("Location: ssl.php");
    exit;
}

if($certName==$cert_auth)
{
    //copy the applied certificate to fireballbundle.crt
    //$output = copysslfb("/portal/data/config/certificate/".$newfile.".crt");
    $error_text="Selfsigned Certicate";
    AddLog("sslconfig.php",$error_text,ERR_DEBUG_HIGH); 
    $output="success";
} 
else 
{
    $error_text="Not Selfsigned Certicate";
    AddLog("sslconfig.php",$error_text,ERR_DEBUG_HIGH);
    $output="success";
}

if($output!="success")
{
    $cmd = "rm -rf /portal/data/config/certificate/tmp/";
    $error_text="Command : ".$cmd;
    AddLog("sslconfig.php",$error_text,ERR_DEBUG_HIGH);
    $output = exec($cmd,$array1,$error_code);
    $error_text="Error code : ".$error_code;
    AddLog("sslconfig.php",$error_text,ERR_DEBUG_HIGH);
    $error_text="Could not add certificate to fireballbundle.crt : ".$output;
    AddLog("sslconfig.php",$error_text,ERR_ERROR);
    seterror('0:|: :|: Error in applying certificate.');
    header("Location: ssl.php");
    exit;
}
```

Now I want to replace exec command with system command ?

I am using three times `exec()` here as shown as above code now i want to replace with `system ()` command in php

```
exec("hostname",$retval);
$output = exec($cmd,$array1,$error_code);
exec($cmd,$array1,$error_code);
```

Answer (score 2):

To remove a single file, you should use [unlink](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) and to remove a directory you should use [rmdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php). In the comments on those pages, you will find many different ways to emulate `rm -rf` through these functions.

You should avoid using `system` or `exec` as much as is possible. Always look on php.net and google to see if you can find a way to do whatever you're trying to do with a built-in function or library. You have no need to use these facilities here.

What `hostname` returns you should probably use [`$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) for instead.

Comment: :) i m also using unlink in my Coding